# FileName seems to be cut off for the first document in an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

In my docusign envelope, I have 2 documents, both using the same server template. I noticed that the first document name is always truncated ( something like "tags for master.docx" and the second document would be "c:\temp\outlookinfo.docx" ). The first document is missing the path information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be an upper character to limit to the document name field, the DocuSign system will simply use whatever filename you provide for the documents so my guess is this issue is a client side bug.

First, I'm not sure you can have `:` character in a filename, some operating systems will not allow that.  Second, you may inadvertently be setting an escape sequence in your filename. For example, the second filename you posted is `c:\temp\outlookinfo.docx`

The `\t` character sequence represents a tab, which you do not want in your filename.  It's possible your other filename that is not getting populated also has an escape sequence like `\r` for carriage return or something similar.

Comment: I have tried it multiple times since, using different documents, and it is always the same for the first document in the envelope. For example, I have 3 documents in the envelope, one server template. The first composite template has the server template and the first document. The second composite template has the other two documents. The envelope definition has the full name of the file.